# Build and deploy a private apk

Tags: android, apk

I created an android app that will be used by 10 users in several Lenovo tablets.

That's why I think I don't need to deploy to Google Play.

In Android Studio, I can create signed apk, and it creates two deploy types; release and debug.
with apk-release.apk and apk-debug.apk files.

Also, I can build an APK, and I get another apk-debug.apk.

The problem is when I try to install in one Lenovo Tablet, any of the apks.
It only accepts apk-debug.apk, the one created with "build"...

What're the steps to deploy a "private" app?

I'm trying not to uninstall the app!

Best regards

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/custom-app-api/publish Check if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Release and debug APKs are signed with different keys I presume (as is most often the case) so you won't be able to install the release APK without first uninstalling the debug APK (which seems to be the one currently installed). This is a security feature of the Android platform.

You have the option to use the debug key for your release APK which would solve your problem but create a security vulnerability since debug keystores are protected by the same password on all installations of the Android SDK, so it could be compromised. Also that would prevent you from ever publishing to Play Store since debug keys are forbidden (for the same reason).

As Novo Lucas pointed out, you should still consider publishing to Play as a private app, so app updates are automatically sent to the devices already having your app. Otherwise, updates will have to be manual and thus quite painful.

Uninstalling the app already installed and reinstalling the one signed with the release key thus seems like the best solution unfortunately.